# Write a polynomal using $t = x - 1$

Tags: calculus

We studied about power series and taylor series. We had a question - to write $p(x) = x^5 + 4x^4 + 7x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 1$ as a polynomal of $p(t) = a_{0} + a_{1}t + \cdots + a_{5}t^5$ where $t = x -1$.

I assume they didn't want me to just write $t + 1$ instead of $x$ and then deal with that enormous equation. Is there a faster way to find the solution using taylor series (or power series) ?

Comment: Simply expanding $p(t+1)$ isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n \ge \deg(p)$ then you have

$$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n {p^{(k)}(1)\over k!}(x-1)^k.$$

Basically... Taylor's theorem.  The Taylor polynomial is a perfect fit if its degree is high enough.

Comment: Why did you choose $x_{0} = 1$ ?

Comment: @Stephanie Because the general formula is
$$p(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{p^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k $$
and you want $t = x-x_0.$